# How to Increase timer Speed C# for Images

Tags: c#, image, timer

I'm fairly new to C# and have mostly done Java. At the moment I am working on a project that has a spinning wheel and a spin button so its pretty simple. I've managed to get the wheel spinning it is currently 624 frames. i have set up a timer to handle the switch between images but as it spins its rather slow and i have interval set to 1 yet its still pretty slow takes about 10 secs to get through all 624 frames. i need it to be at least 4 secs for all 624 frames then gradually slow down.

here is some of my code below.

```
private void Spin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {// button to start the timer          
        if (spin == 0) {
            spin = 1;
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 53));
            spin = 0;
            st.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            st.Interval = 1;
            st.Start();
        }

    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        t1 = t1 + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("" + t1);
        if (t1 == 1)
        {
            Wheel.Image = global::WheelOfFortune.Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0001;
        }
        else if (t1 == 2)
        {
            Wheel.Image = global::WheelOfFortune.Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0002;
        } //etc x 624 then t1 = 0 to repeat
```

Any ideas would be great guys.

If you need further info let me know

Comment: You actually wrote the if 624 times?! wow...

Comment: more like copy and paste and find and replace lol

Comment: Timers have fairly poor resolutions and you can't get them to fire every 1ms. I believe the the limit is around 15ms.

Comment: eh it only took me 5 mins to copy and paste the code ill sort that out later

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212611/raise-event-in-high-resolution-interval-timer

Comment: i see what you mean how else can i rotate between the images at a faster speed, i had timers in java and they did the trick they were so fast i had to slow them down. would i have to remove some frames?

Comment: 624 images in 10 seconds is the speed at which the monitor repaints.  You _cannot_ get any faster than that.

Comment: Note that `Resources.XXX` will re-load the image every time it's accessed.  You should cache that.

Comment: See if this answer helps - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22862989/259769

Comment: I suspect you could use one wheel image and rotate it in code. You might want to try that approach.

Comment: @default.kramer their is also a peg on the wheel clicking over each slot on the wheel so unfortunately i don't think i can do that

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks this look like what i need to do but I can barely read what it does and how to implement it.

Comment: hmm if i increase t1 = t1 +1 to +6 it goes the speed i want and i can gradually change the number down to slow it down this seems to work. for some reason though the first spin goes perfect the second one goes messed up and glitches everywhere do i need to reset the timer somehow?